# Cambiar valor de un dato de archivo .CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv

tengo un archivo .csv con una columna de edad querría cambiar todos los valores que estén por debajo de 18 a "menores de edad" aquellos entre 18 y 65 a "adultos" y a los que sean mayores de 65 a "jubilados"
Alguna idea de como hacer esto de manera rápida sin tener que ir uno por uno?
He probado con la condición If y un bucle pero estos casi seguro que se puede hacer con pandas.

Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Como bien dices con pandas se puede hacer y es más sencillo. Pero te recomiendo que pruebes a poner tu código para intentar ver en qué ayudarte, ya que no se qué nivel o familiaridad tienes con la librería Pandas.

Una opción sencilla, pero con truco es hacer uso de loc.

```
df = pd.Dataframe() # Con los datos que tengas, haces la recogida de datos del df
df.loc[(df["edad"] >= 18), "edad"] = "Mayor edad"
df.loc[(df["edad"] < 18), "edad"] = "Menor edad"
df.loc[(df["edad"] > 65), "edad"] = "Jubilado"
```

Como ves, filtramos por edad y asignamos a la columna "edad" el valor. El problema que te encontrarás con esta opción es que al modificar el dataframe y modificar los datos, modificas también su tipo. Por lo que una vez modifiques el valor mayor a 18, ya la comprobación no valdrá y tendrás error. Por eso una posible solución es crear una columna nueva con los datos, tal que así:

```
df = pd.Dataframe() # Con los datos que tengas, haces la recogida de datos del df
df.loc[(df["edad"] >= 18), "Condition"] = "Mayor edad"
df.loc[(df["edad"] < 18), "Condition"] = "Menor edad"
df.loc[(df["edad"] > 65), "Condition"] = "Jubilado"
```

Así tienes una columna con edad y una nueva con Condition... y si quieres eliminar la columna edad del df solo aplicas un drop con inplace a true y lo tienes.

```
df.drop(columns=["edad"], inplace=True)
```

PD: Te adjunto un enlace con la documentación de [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/index.html). Un saludo
Y se me olvidaba y modifico, para leer los datos de un csv en pandas:

```
df = pd.read_csv("ruta/nombre_archivo")
```

Comment: Muy buena respuesta!!! Muchas gracias

Comment: De nada, @JoseRamonMedinaLorente solo espero que te haya servido y sigas aprendiendo. Un apunte importante en la lectura de csv es que tengan los datos bien, a veces puede dar error por espacios. Prueba el código a ver qué tal. Y una cosa más. el uso del inplace a True es para que el dataframe se actualice y no tengas que asignarlo a otra variable. Un saludo